# AppEngine Datastore - Does updating entity delete child entities?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The official documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities is not clear on the parent relationship of the Datastore: "The Datastore API does not distinguish between creating a new entity and updating an existing one" SO, does saving entity with the same key not only updates properties but also deletes descendant entities?

Answer (score 0):

According to the test on my local machine (simulated datastore), updating properties does not delete descendant entities. Therefore updates are possible, although are not reflected in the syntax of API.